# TableExport jquery plugin: Filename and Extension issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, csv, export-to-csv

I am using [tableexport.js](https://github.com/kayalshri/tableExport.jquery.plugin) to export my html table into different formats like excel, csv, pdf etc.

In tableexport.js, there is code for filename and extension which is not working.

```
window.open('data:application/'+defaults.type+';filename=exportData;' + base64data);
```

When i click export, browser opens the dialog to save as / open with. Issue i am facing is that there is no filename & extension if i save the file.I just want to export my html table to csv with custom filename. Conversion to csv is working but i have to type name + extension to save the file. How to fix this issue.

Answer (score 6):

Replace tableexport.js with below code, files will start download after export:

```
(function(f,a){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define([],a):"object"==typeof exports?module.exports=a():f.download=a()})(this,function(){return function(f,a,b){function n(l){var a=l.split(/[:;,]/);l=a[1];var a=("base64"==a[2]?atob:decodeURIComponent)(a.pop()),c=a.length,b=0,d=new Uint8Array(c);for(b;b<c;++b)d[b]=a.charCodeAt(b);return new g([d],{type:l})}function k(a,b){if("download"in d)return d.href=a,d.setAttribute("download",m),d.innerHTML="downloading...",h.body.appendChild(d),setTimeout(function(){d.click(),h.body.removeChild(d),!0===b&&setTimeout(function(){e.URL.revokeObjectURL(d.href)},250)},66),!0;if("undefined"!=typeof safari)return a="data:"+a.replace(/^data:([\w\/\-\+]+)/,"application/octet-stream"),!window.open(a)&&confirm("Displaying New Document\n\nUse Save As... to download, then click back to return to this page.")&&(location.href=a),!0;var c=h.createElement("iframe");h.body.appendChild(c),b||(a="data:"+a.replace(/^data:([\w\/\-\+]+)/,"application/octet-stream")),c.src=a,setTimeout(function(){h.body.removeChild(c)},333)}var e=window;b=b||"application/octet-stream";var c=f,h=document,d=h.createElement("a");f=function(a){return String(a)};var g=e.Blob||e.MozBlob||e.WebKitBlob||f,g=g.call?g.bind(e):Blob,m=a||"download";"true"===String(this)&&(c=[c,b],b=c[0],c=c[1]);if(String(c).match(/^data\:[\w+\-]+\/[\w+\-]+[,;]/))return navigator.msSaveBlob?navigator.msSaveBlob(n(c),m):k(c);a=c instanceof g?c:new g([c],{type:b});if(navigator.msSaveBlob)return navigator.msSaveBlob(a,m);if(e.URL)k(e.URL.createObjectURL(a),!0);else{if("string"==typeof a||a.constructor===f)try{return k("data:"+b+";base64,"+e.btoa(a))}catch(p){return k("data:"+b+","+encodeURIComponent(a))}b=new FileReader,b.onload=function(a){k(this.result)},b.readAsDataURL(a)}return!0}});
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        tableExport: function(options) {
            var defaults = {
                    separator: ',',
                    ignoreColumn: [],
                    tableName:'yourTableName',
                    type:'csv',
                    pdfFontSize:14,
                    pdfLeftMargin:20,
                    escape:'true',
                    htmlContent:'false',
                    consoleLog:'false'
            };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        var el = this;

        if(defaults.type == 'csv' || defaults.type == 'txt'){

            // Header
            var tdData ="";
            $(el).find('thead').find('tr').each(function() {
            tdData += "\n";                 
                $(this).filter(':visible').find('th').each(function(index,data) {
                    if ($(this).css('display') != 'none'){
                        if(defaults.ignoreColumn.indexOf(index) == -1){
                            tdData += '"' + parseString($(this)) + '"' + defaults.separator;                                    
                        }
                    }
                });
                tdData = $.trim(tdData);
                tdData = $.trim(tdData).substring(0, tdData.length -1);
            });

            // Row vs Column
            $(el).find('tbody').find('tr').each(function() {
            tdData += "\n";
                $(this).filter(':visible').find('td').each(function(index,data) {
                    if ($(this).css('display') != 'none'){
                        if(defaults.ignoreColumn.indexOf(index) == -1){
                            tdData += '"'+ parseString($(this)) + '"'+ defaults.separator;
                        }
                    }
                });
                //tdData = $.trim(tdData);
                tdData = $.trim(tdData).substring(0, tdData.length -1);
            });

            //output
            if(defaults.consoleLog == 'true'){
                console.log(tdData);
            }
            var base64data = "base64," + $.base64.encode(tdData);
            //window.open('data:application/'+defaults.type+';filename=exportData;' + base64data);
            download('data:text/plain;'+base64data,'download.'+defaults.type,'text/plain');
        }else if(defaults.type == 'sql'){

            // Header
            var tdData ="INSERT INTO `"+defaults.tableName+"` (";
            $(el).find('thead').find('tr').each(function() {

                $(this).filter(':visible').find('th').each(function(index,data) {
                    if ($(this).css('display') != 'none'){
                        if(defaults.ignoreColumn.indexOf(index) == -1){
                            tdData += '`' + parseString($(this)) + '`,' ;                                   
                        }
                    }
                });
                tdData = $.trim(tdData);
                tdData = $.trim(tdData).substring(0, tdData.length -1);
            });
            tdData += ") VALUES ";
            // Row vs Column
            $(el).find('tbody').find('tr').each(function() {
            tdData += "(";
                $(this).filter(':visible').find('td').each(function(index,data) {
                    if ($(this).css('display') != 'none'){
                        if(defaults.ignoreColumn.indexOf(index) == -1){
                            tdData += '"'+ parseString($(this)) + '",';
                        }
                    }
                });

                tdData = $.trim(tdData).substring(0, tdData.length -1);
                tdData += "),";
            });
            tdData = $.trim(tdData).substring(0, tdData.length -1);
            tdData += ";";

            //output
            //console.log(tdData);

            if(defaults.consoleLog == 'true'){
                console.log(tdData);
            }

            var base64data = "base64," + $.base64.encode(tdData);
            //window.open('data:text/plain;filename=filename.sql;' + base64data);
            download('data:text/plain;'+base64data,'download.'+defaults.type,'text/plain');

        }else if(defaults.type == 'json'){

            var jsonHeaderArray = [];
            $(el).find('thead').find('tr').each(function() {
                var tdData =""; 
                var jsonArrayTd = [];

                $(this).filter(':visible').find('th').each(function(index,data) {
                    if ($(this).css('display') != 'none'){
                        if(defaults.ignoreColumn.indexOf(index) == -1){
                            jsonArrayTd.push(parseString($(this)));                                 
                        }
                    }
                });                                 
                jsonHeaderArray.push(jsonArrayTd);                      

            });

            var jsonArray = [];
            $(el).find('tbody').find('tr').each(function() {
                var tdData =""; 
                var jsonArrayTd = [];

                $(this).filter(':visible').find('td').each(function(index,data) {
                    if ($(this).css('display') != 'none'){
                        if(defaults.ignoreColumn.indexOf(index) == -1){
                            jsonArrayTd.push(parseString($(this)));                                 
                        }
                    }
                });                                 
                jsonArray.push(jsonArrayTd);                                    

            });

            var jsonExportArray =[];
            jsonExportArray.push({header:jsonHeaderArray,data:jsonArray});

            //Return as JSON
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonExportArray));

            //Return as Array
            //console.log(jsonExportArray);
            if(defaults.consoleLog == 'true'){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonExportArray));
            }
            var base64data = "base64," + $.base64.encode(JSON.stringify(jsonExportArray));
            //window.open('data:application/json;filename=exportData;' + base64data);
            download('data:application/json;'+base64data,'download.'+defaults.type,'application/json');
        }else if(defaults.type == 'xml'){

            var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
            xml += '<tabledata><fields>';

            // Header
            $(el).find('thead').find('tr').each(function() {
                $(this).filter(':visible').find('th').each(function(index,data) {
                    if ($(this).css('display') != 'none'){                  
                        if(defaults.ignoreColumn.indexOf(index) == -1){
                            xml += "<field>" + parseString($(this)) + "</field>";
                        }
                    }
                });                                 
            });                 
            xml += '</fields><data>';

            // Row Vs Column
            var rowCount=1;
            $(el).find('tbody').find('tr').each(function() {
                xml += '<row id="'+rowCount+'">';
                var colCount=0;
                $(this).filter(':visible').find('td').each(function(index,data) {
                    if ($(this).css('display') != 'none'){  
                        if(defaults.ignoreColumn.indexOf(index) == -1){
                            xml += "<column-"+colCount+">"+parseString($(this))+"</column-"+colCount+">";
                        }
                    }
                    colCount++;
                });                                                         
                rowCount++;
                xml += '</row>';
            });                 
            xml += '</data></tabledata>'

            if(defaults.consoleLog == 'true'){
                console.log(xml);
            }

            var base64data = "base64," + $.base64.encode(xml);
            //window.open('data:application/xml;filename=exportData;' + base64data);
            download('data:application/xml;'+base64data,'download.'+defaults.type,'application/xml');

        }else if(defaults.type == 'excel' || defaults.type == 'doc'|| defaults.type == 'powerpoint'  ){

            //console.log($(this).html());
            var excel="<table>";
            // Header
            $(el).find('thead').find('tr').each(function() {
                excel += "<tr>";
                $(this).filter(':visible').find('th').each(function(index,data) {
                    if ($(this).css('display') != 'none'){                  
                        if(defaults.ignoreColumn.indexOf(index) == -1){
                            excel += "<td>" + parseString($(this))+ "</td>";
                        }
                    }
                }); 
                excel += '</tr>';                       

            });

            // Row Vs Column
            var rowCount=1;
            $(el).find('tbody').find('tr').each(function() {
                excel += "<tr>";
                var colCount=0;
                $(this).filter(':visible').find('td').each(function(index,data) {
                    if ($(this).css('display') != 'none'){  
                        if(defaults.ignoreColumn.indexOf(index) == -1){
                            excel += "<td>"+parseString($(this))+"</td>";
                        }
                    }
                    colCount++;
                });                                                         
                rowCount++;
                excel += '</tr>';
            });                 
            excel += '</table>'

            if(defaults.consoleLog == 'true'){
                console.log(excel);
            }

            var excelFile = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:x='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:"+defaults.type+"' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>";
            excelFile += "<head>";
            excelFile += "<!--[if gte mso 9]>";
            excelFile += "<xml>";
            excelFile += "<x:ExcelWorkbook>";
            excelFile += "<x:ExcelWorksheets>";
            excelFile += "<x:ExcelWorksheet>";
            excelFile += "<x:Name>";
            excelFile += "{worksheet}";
            excelFile += "</x:Name>";
            excelFile += "<x:WorksheetOptions>";
            excelFile += "<x:DisplayGridlines/>";
            excelFile += "</x:WorksheetOptions>";
            excelFile += "</x:ExcelWorksheet>";
            excelFile += "</x:ExcelWorksheets>";
            excelFile += "</x:ExcelWorkbook>";
            excelFile += "</xml>";
            excelFile += "<![endif]-->";
            excelFile += "</head>";
            excelFile += "<body>";
            excelFile += excel;
            excelFile += "</body>";
            excelFile += "</html>";

            var base64data = "base64," + $.base64.encode(excelFile);
            switch(defaults.type){
                case 'excel':
                    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-'+defaults.type+';'+base64data);
                break;
                case 'powerpoint':
                    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-'+defaults.type+';'+base64data);
                break;
                case 'doc':
                    download('data:application/msword;'+base64data,'download.doc','application/msword');
                break;
            }

        }else if(defaults.type == 'png'){
            html2canvas($(el), {
                onrendered: function(canvas) {                                      
                    var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                    window.open(img);
                }
            });     
        }else if(defaults.type == 'pdf'){

            var doc = new jsPDF('p','pt', 'a4', true);
            doc.setFontSize(defaults.pdfFontSize);

            // Header
            var startColPosition=defaults.pdfLeftMargin;
            $(el).find('thead').find('tr').each(function() {
                $(this).filter(':visible').find('th').each(function(index,data) {
                    if ($(this).css('display') != 'none'){                  
                        if(defaults.ignoreColumn.indexOf(index) == -1){
                            var colPosition = startColPosition+ (index * 50);                                   
                            doc.text(colPosition,20, parseString($(this)));
                        }
                    }
                });                                 
            });                 

            // Row Vs Column
            var startRowPosition = 20; var page =1;var rowPosition=0;
            $(el).find('tbody').find('tr').each(function(index,data) {
                rowCalc = index+1;

            if (rowCalc % 26 == 0){
                doc.addPage();
                page++;
                startRowPosition=startRowPosition+10;
            }
            rowPosition=(startRowPosition + (rowCalc * 10)) - ((page -1) * 280);

                $(this).filter(':visible').find('td').each(function(index,data) {
                    if ($(this).css('display') != 'none'){  
                        if(defaults.ignoreColumn.indexOf(index) == -1){
                            var colPosition = startColPosition+ (index * 50);                                   
                            doc.text(colPosition,rowPosition, parseString($(this)));
                        }
                    }

                });                                                         

            });

            // Output as Data URI
            doc.output('datauri');

        }

        function parseString(data){

            if(defaults.htmlContent == 'true'){
                content_data = data.html().trim();
            }else{
                content_data = data.text().trim();
            }

            if(defaults.escape == 'true'){
                content_data = escape(content_data);
            }

            return content_data;
        }

    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

---

> Code copied from @khadkamhn on kayalshri/tableExport.jquery.plugin github
>   repo [issue 21](https://github.com/kayalshri/tableExport.jquery.plugin/issues/21)

Comment: Thanks for the solution it helped

Comment: Good Job! Friend!!